# Quotient ring, example about $( r_1 +I)( r_2 +I)\ne r_1r_2+I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Could one construct a ring $R$ and an  two-sided ideal $I$ in $R$ such that there exist $r_1, r_2\in R$ with $(r_1 +I)(r_2 +I)\ne r_1r_2+I$? (Here $(r_1 +I)(r_2 +I)=\{( r_1 +a)( r_2 +b)\mid a,b\in I\}$.)

---

Well, I am learning about [Quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring). We know that $(r_1 +I)(r_2 +I)\subseteq r_1r_2+I$.

Comment: When you write "ideal", do you mean a left-ideal, or a two-sided ideal? The mention of quotient rings suggests two-sided ideals.

Comment: en,   two-sided ideal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $r_1=r_2=0$. Note that $I^2=4\mathbb{Z}\subsetneq I$.